# loading and compiling template in ratpack: blocking or not?

Tags: ratpack, pebble

I'm adding [Pebble template](http://www.mitchellbosecke.com/pebble/home) support to my ratpack application, and there is one matter that bothers me: should my `RendererSupport` instance use ratpack's `Blocking.get()` or not? As PebbleEngine has it's own cache, i can't say whether it would be loading template source from disk, so it is (possibly) an IO operation.
Looking at handlebars templating implementation i can't see any special treat of the IO operation.

So my question is: is it the rule of thumb to use `Blocking` for all the potentially IO-bound operations (e.g. filesystem or db access), or there is some more complicated rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Pebble's cache is indefinite (Handlebars' one is) then I would say you can do the same as what Ratpack's integration for Handlebars does - depend on the cache and run the code that can potentially load the template from disk on the compute thread. You will pay a performance penalty every time a template is loaded for the first time (because you will run blocking code on a compute thread) but it will go away as your cache coverage increases.

Note that there is [an issue](https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack/issues/219) in the tracker that aims at removing that performance penalty for the Handlebars integration by precompiling templates and thus populating the cache on startup.

Comment: that is exactly what i was thinking, but wasn't 100% sure. Thanks!